# osx: how do I find the size of the disk i/o cache (write cache, for example)

Tags: macos, iokit

I am looking to optimize my disk IO, and am looking around to try to find out what the disk cache size is. system_profiler is not telling me, where else can I look?

edit:  my program is processing entire volumes: I'm doing a secure-wipe, so I loop through all of the blocks on the volume, reading, randomizing the data, writing... if I read/write 4k blocks per IO operation the entire job is significantly faster than r/w a single block per operation. so my question stems from my search to find the ideal size of a r/w operation (ideal in terms of performance:speed). please do not point out that for a wipe-program I don't need the read operation, just assume that I do. thx.

Comment: Do you mean the filesystem cache of OSX, or the RAM chips on the physical HDD controller?

Comment: @MSalters: I think the hardware cache size is what I'm looking for. I edited the question in order to be more specific. thx.

Answer (score 7):

Mac OS X uses a Unified Buffer Cache. What that means is that in the kernel VM objects and files are them at some level, same thing, and the size of the available memory for caching is entirely dependent on the VM pressure in the rest of the system. It also means the read and write caching is unified, if an item in the read cache is written to it just gets marked dirty and then will be written to disk when changes are committed.

So the disk cache may be very small or gigabytes large, and dynamically changes as the system is used. Because of this trying to determine the cache size and optimize based on it is a losing fight. You are much better off looking at doing things that inform the cache how to operate better, like checking with the underlying device's optimal IO size is, or identifying data that should not be cached and using F_NOCACHE.

Comment: thank you Louis for the very informative answer.
follow-up question then would be: how does one detect the underlying device's optimal IO size? 
thx!
\|K<

Comment: @Louis: re:"From write() down to the flash chips" very nice posting. thanks for the infos!

Comment: Your best bet is to use the statfs() system call and look at the f_iosize member of the returned struct.